# No results when using -c option in tr command

Tags: tr

No translation occurs when using -c option in tr command in linux.
For example `tr -c "[:digit:]" "#"` or `tr -c [:digit:] "#"`. When I type text like `abc` instaed of `###`, nothing happens.
Input: `qwe123ty12.`
Expected output: `###123##12#`
Current output: `###123##12##`

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's your input and what output do you expect?

Comment: What exactly is your whole command? How do you pipe your input to `tr`? `tr -c "[:digit:]" "#" <<< abc` has the expected output for me.

Comment: input: "qwe123ty12." expected output: "###123##12#" something like this. All the input comes from keyboard

Comment: So, you run `tr -c "[:digit:]" "#"` interactively, then you enter `qwe123ty12.`, and then? You hit Ctrl-D to end input? Is this part of a script? [Edit] your question instead of adding information in comments.

Comment: hitting Ctrl+D works but i don't understand why the output is "###123##12##" instead of "###123##12#". Is EOF being translated too?

Comment: I mistyped it..

Comment: Are you typing a literal `.` and a newline? Both the `.` and the newline will be translated to `#`.  There is no "EOF" to be translated, but there is a newline character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, that's a character, too: Newline (sometimes written as `\n`).

Your character class includes all non-digit characters, including newline. That's why every time you hit Enter, another `#` is added to the output. It's not immediately visible because output is only flushed when a newline is printed (which never happens with your set of options) or when the end of the input is reached (which is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> for interactive input).

You can exempt newline from being turned into `#` by doing

```
tr -c '[:digit:]\n' '#'
```

This adds `\n` to the set of characters to be left alone.